# Using any separator in datePicker textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using bootstrap-datepicker to select dates. Here is my code:

```
$(document).on('ready', function () { 
    $('.dtp').datepicker({
        format: "dd/mm/yyyy", 
        autoclose: true, 
        keyboardNavigation: true
    });    
});
```

It works fine as it is. But now I would like to enter date as follows:

```
15-07-2016
15/07/2016
15.07.2016
```

I mean I should be allowed to use any separator. But currently only 1 separator is valid. Others are not. Why??

```
15-07-2016 // Invalid
15/07/2016 // Valid
15.07.2016 // Invalid
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [extraFormats](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/pull/666)?

```
$(document).on('ready', function(){

    $('.dtp').datepicker({
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy", 
    extraFormats: ["dd-mm-yyyy", "dd.mm.yyyy"],
    autoclose: true, 
    keyboardNavigation: true});

});
```

Comment: Let me know the error(s) please, look into your console too and see if you get anything regarding this?

Comment: No errors!!!!! When I type date using `/` format, date is selected in calendar but when I type using `-` or `.`, date is not selected in calendar.